# FOSJSRoutingBundle : "Route xxx does not exist"

Tags: php, javascript, symfony

I'm facing a really weird problem with FOSJSRoutingBundle :

First of all, here is my configuration : I'm working on Symfony 2.0.23 and with JQuery, on Windows 7 64 bits with a WAMP (Apache 2.4.2 and PHP 5.4.3). 
I've done all the settings from the FOSJSRoutingBundle's github and haved exposed my routes ( almost all the related problems I could find by googling (on FOSJSRoutingBundle's github,here and on different forums) were because people have not exposed their routes, but I tried php app/console fos:js-routing:debug and I do see my routes).
The js is added to the layout (code of the layout at the end).

Trying to generate url for routes in js, at the beginning I wanted to generate two different routes but for test I created the js code below :

```
    //Code inside this function is working
    $("select").change(function () {
      param=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;
      test1=Routing.generate('myBundle_step3', { myParam: param });
      alert(test1);
      window.location=Routing.generate('myBundle_step2');
    });
    //Code inside this one is also working
    $('input[type="checkbox"]').change(function() {
      test=Routing.generate('myBundle_step2');
    }).change();
    //This is not working
    test=Routing.generate('myBundle_step2');
    alert(test);
```

With this code, I get the javaScript error "The route myBundle_step2 does not exist". Though the first part still works (alert gives me the link created and the redirection goes well). 
If I remove the second function, I do not get the Javascript error anymore.

If in the second function I replace step2 by step3, the error becomes "The route myBundle_step3 does not exist".
I tried to clear the cache and to run php app/console asset:install --symlink again, but no results.

Here is the controller corresponding code (the real code is a bit long and I don't think it's relevant, if you think so, I could put it anyways :

```
    namespace my\Bundle\Controller;
    class IndividuController extends Controller
    {
      public function step2Action() {
        Some code
      }
      public function step3Action($myParam) {
        Some code
      }
    }
```

The routing.yml config file relative to the bundle :

```
    myBundle_step2:
      pattern: /step/2
      defaults: {_controller: myBundle:Individu:step2}
      options:
        expose: true
    myBundle_step3:
      pattern: /step/3/{myParam}
      defaults: {_controller: myBundle:Individu:step3}
      options:
        expose: true
```

The app/config/routing.yml file :

```
    fos_js_routing:
      resource: "@FOSJsRoutingBundle/Resources/config/routing/routing.xml"

    myBundle:
      resource: "@myBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml"
      prefix:   /
```

The layout's relevant informations :

```
     <!-- jQuery via Google + local fallback, see h5bp.com -->
        <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">    </script>
        <script>window.jQuery || document.write('<script src="js/jquery-1.7.1.min.js"><\/script>')</script>
           {% javascripts 'bootstrap/js/bootstrap.js'
                        'bundles/fosjsrouting/js/router.js'
                        'bundles/crrisuaps/js/suaps.js' %}
               <script type="text/javascript" src="{{ asset_url }}"></script>
           {% endjavascripts %}
        <script src="{{ path('fos_js_routing_js', {"callback": "fos.Router.setData"}) }}"></script>
       </body>
    </html>
```

Result of php app/console router:debug (I left only the relevant informations + I left the undefined variable notice just in case, it's a notice I got since I added this library, still the library works and I do not think the problem could come from here :

> C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps>php app/console router:debug
>
> Notice: Undefined variable: kPathUrl in C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html2
>       pdf_class\tcpdfConfig.php on line 80
>
> Call Stack:
>          0.0070     231536   1. {main}() C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\console:0
>          0.0209     685656   2. require_once('C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\bootstr
>       ap.php.cache') C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\console:10
>          0.0212     701752   3. require_once('C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\autoloa
>       d.php') C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\bootstrap.php.cache:3
>          0.1335    2998152   4. require_once('C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html
>       2pdf\html2pdf.class.php') C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\app\autoload.php:51
>          0.1379    3361792   5. require_once('C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html
>       2pdf_class\myPdf.class.php') C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html2pdf\html2p
>       df.class.php:19
>          0.1385    3393792   6. require_once('C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html
>       2pdf_class\tcpdfConfig.php') C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps\vendor\html2pdf_class
>       \myPdf.class.php:12

[router] Current routes

```
    Name                                            Method Pattern
    _assetic_55f0319                                ANY    /css/55f0319.css
    _assetic_55f0319_0                              ANY    /css/55f0319_bootstrap_1.
    css
    _assetic_55f0319_1                              ANY    /css/55f0319_bootstrap-re
    sponsive_2.css
    _assetic_55f0319_2                              ANY    /css/55f0319_style_3.css
    _assetic_3608a04                                ANY    /js/3608a04.js
    _assetic_3608a04_0                              ANY    /js/3608a04_bootstrap_1.j
    s
    _assetic_3608a04_1                              ANY    /js/3608a04_router_2.js
    _assetic_3608a04_2                              ANY    /js/3608a04_suaps_3.js

    fos_js_routing_js                               ANY    /js/routing.{_format}
    myBundle_homepage                        ANY    /

    myBundle_inscription_etape1              ANY    /inscription/etape/1
    myBundle_inscription_etape2              ANY    /inscription/etape/2
    myBundle_inscription_etape3              ANY    /inscription/etape/3/{dis
    ciplineSelection}
```

Result of php app/console fos:js-routing:debug (I removed the PHP Notice but it happens on every command I make btw) :

```
    C:\wamp\www\suapsRepo\suaps>php app/console fos:js-routing:debug
    [router] Current routes
    Name                               Method Pattern
    crrisuapsBundle_inscription_etape2 ANY    /inscription/etape/2
    crrisuapsBundle_inscription_etape3 ANY    /inscription/etape/3/{disciplineSelect
    ion}
```

Edit : Also, don't know if it's relevant but when I try 'php app/console fos:js-routing:debug myBundle_step2' I get the following php error :

> [Error Exception]
>   Warning: Missing argument 3 for Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\RouterDebugCommand:outputRoute(), called in C:\symfonyDirectory\vendor\bundles\FOS\JsRoutingBundle\Command\RouterDebugExposedCommand.php on line 62 and defined in C:\serverDirectory\vendor\symfony\src\Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Command\RouterDebugCommand.php line 98

Comment: Can you show us your Controller of these two actions with the annotations/xml configuration of your routing?

Comment: I edited and added all the routing.yml + the controller code.

Comment: Have you added the js to your layout? See [here](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSJsRoutingBundle/blob/master/Resources/doc/README.markdown#usage)

Comment: Yes the js is added to the layout, sorry I forgot to mention it in topic's body. I edit.

Comment: In the routing.yml the param of "myBundle_step3" is `aParam` but in the js is `myParam`. It's a typo?

Comment: Yes sorry, I correct it.

Comment: `Routing.generate('myBundle_step2'})` is `}` a typo?

Comment: Yes, added it when I corrected last time -_- 
Now corrected, thanks.

Comment: And if you try the routes directly do they work? What if you use `$this->get('router')->generate('myBundle_step3')` in a controller? I don't know if it's an issue but in your route `myBundle_step3` you have a parameter you don't use: `{myParam}`. Can you post the result of: `php app/console router:debug`?

Comment: Using `$this->get('router')->generate('myBundle_step3')` works well.
For the not used parameter, I just forgot it when I was clarifying problem, I'll just add it.
I post the result of `php app/console router:debug"` in the body's topic for more lisibility. 
Thanks for your quick answers/your help.

Comment: Your routes don't match the config but I assume this is because you initially simplified your config in the question? Do you get the same error than when you run `php app/console fos:js-routing:debug myBundle_step2`? Can you run `php app/console fos:js-routing:debug` (without any parameter) and post the result?

Comment: Yes it is because I simplified, the PHP Notice pops in every php command if it is what you asked. 
Maybe you wanted to know if I get the php `[Error Exception]` I mentionned at the end when I run `php app/console fos:js-routing:debug myBundle_step2` with `myBundle_step3`, the answer is yes, same error than with `myBundle_step2`.
I've added the result of `php app/console fos:js-routing:debug` in the body's topic.

Comment: I have tried your code in on of my project and can't reproduce...I use Jquery 1.9.1, FOSJSRoutingBundle version 1.1.5 and Symfony 2.2. Maybe there is a difference between the 2.0 and 2.2 than could cause this??

Comment: Just tried on symfony 2.2.1, JQuery 1.9.1 and FOSJSRoutingBundle 1.1.5, I get the same error... I must be missing a problem in config files or something like that... But this is a really strange problem, as even if I get an error, the first routes work well.

Comment: Ok, I now know what is the problem, which might not be really a problem, the code example I gave, which I thought was not working, was actually working, the problem is when I try to do a Routing.generate() outside of the functions, if I only try to generate routes in the functions' code like above, it's working (ps: I edit topic's body to be better understood). Is that a normal behaviour?

Comment: For those who search on this error - something like this also might help: bin/console fos:js-routing:dump --format=json --target=web/js/fos-js-routes.json

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I also had this problem. Setting the `options.expose` parameter on the routing configuration solved it for me.

**routing.yml**

```
cart_edit:
    pattern:  /Cart/edit
    defaults: { _controller: CartCartBundle:Default:cart_edit }
    options:
        expose: true
```

**my.js**

```
var url = Routing.generate('cart_edit');
$.post(url, function(data) {
      //do somthing
});
```

Change as needed. Hope this will solve your problem.

Comment: Worked for me, this should be accepted answer. It is written in the jsRouting docs, but not highlighted enough for hurrisome devs like me.

Comment: Couldn't check it since I don't have the project anymore (previous company) but given the high rates of upvote I guess that solution is working so accepted.

Comment: Thanks, Worked for me.

Comment: I was going crazy with it! Thank you so much!! The docs are really poor on this... In fact, there are a few things that confuse (like the import and stuff... I guess that's for NodeJs, right?).

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue and the problem was in my config file. Try checking for this:

```
# app/config/config.yml
fos_js_routing:
    routes_to_expose: [ myBundle_step2, myBundle_step3, ... ]
```

Answer (score 5):

Just for completeness: it is also possible to use annotations (`options={"expose"=true}`) as explained in the [documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/master/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html#generating-uris):

```
// src/AppBundle/Controller/DefaultController.php

/**
 * @Route("/foo/{id}/bar", options={"expose"=true}, name="my_route_to_expose")
 */
public function indexAction($foo) {
    // ...
}
```

This also works for routes sets at controller level (example from one of my controllers):

```
/**
 * Channel controller.
 *
 * @Route("account/{account}/todos", options={"expose"=true})
 * @ParamConverter("account", class="AppBundle:Account", options={
 *     "repository_method" = "findOneById",
 *     "mapping": {"account": "id"},
 *     "map_method_signature" = true
 * })
 */
class TodoListController extends Controller
{
```

Comment: Thanks. I was so eager to try that I didn't read your answer... could have saved a couple of minutes :)

Comment: The options={"expose"=true}, annotation did the trick!